# Is it possible to rebind Ctrl+Alt to the Meta key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, awesome

I'm using the [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) window manager, and it's, well, awesome.

However, I have a slight issue - I'm using an IBM Model M keyboard, which lacks the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key.

This is kind of a problem, as awesome relies on it for basically every action you can make.

I do tend to use my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys quite often, so I'm not really able to remap those - however what I would like to be able to do is remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to fire a meta event. Is this possible? I've toyed around with xkeycaps and done some searches on "rebind ctrl+alt" but most of the results give me either swapping the two keys or something else. (Also, I use caps-lock as an additional control, or I would just map that one.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to map ctrl + alt key combination to Mod4 that is windows or super or meta key. but it did not worked. I think you can not assign only ctrl alt combination. you need something with that combiunation e.g. ctrl alt d etc. Why dont you use some Function key for meta?

Comment: @Abhijit, that would probably work, but it would be an awkward key combination. If I can't figure out how, I'll probably just try mapping left-alt to meta as I use that one less-frequently.

Comment: What about CapsLock and NumLock? Some time ago I map them both to super and use for window switching. I really did not missed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible, you'll have to find some other key that you use less often.